# Get the text between a parent tag and its first child using BeatifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Let's say I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<p class="toSelect">
    "some text here..."
    <br>
    "Other text here..."
</p>
```

any suggestions to how to get the first text between the `<p>` tag and its `<br>` child tag using Beautifulsoup in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select element `<p class="toSelect">` and then `.find_next` with `text=True`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<p class="toSelect">
    "some text here..."
    <br>
    "Other text here..."
</p>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

text = soup.select_one(".toSelect").find_next(text=True)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
    "some text here..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.contents` of `<p>` to get all the text and children of `<p>` and select the first item from the list.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<p class="toSelect">
    "some text here..."
    <br>
    "Other text here..."
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find('p')
print(x.contents[0].strip())
```

```
Output:

"some text here..."
```

*You can read more about `.contents` - [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)*